# Invoking "cmake" failed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please how do I fix this error

```
ubuntu@arm:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/install" in "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/test_results
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.9
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I am new and I dont't what this means. I appreciate all help to fix this error

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196915/invoking-%22cmake%22-failed/) by [Glory](https://answers.ros.org/users/19749/glory/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2014-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems you do not have any C++ compilers installed. You must first install one to use catkin like this.
Try opening up a terminal and then typing:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential -y
```

Then the g++ compiler should be installed.

---

Originally posted by [hiro64](https://answers.ros.org/users/20213/hiro64/) with karma: 58 on 2014-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [addext](https://answers.ros.org/users/45331/addext/) on 2019-09-03**:
I already had it installed - this does not fix it. Any more suggestions?